# Local External Drive Backup for WinServer 2012 R2 Essentials

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012-r2, storage-spaces

Right now a client of mine has a WinServer 2012 R2 Essentials machine with three hard drives in it - one is the main C: drive for the OS, and the remaining two are using Storage Spaces for drive mirroring and are set up as one drive that is the company's "network drive".

Currently we have CrashPlan PROe (Enterprise Edition) set up on this server and it has two backup destinations - a local external drive and CrashPlan's cloud storage (CrashPlan Central).  The problem is with the amount of data on the "network drive" (around 5 TB) and the relatively slow upload speeds (around 20 Mbps upload).  As a result, we are constantly in a backup deficit with the cloud backup (at this point it needs to upload 1.8 TB of data) and because the one CrashPlan application is handling both the local external drive backup and the cloud backup, for some reason it is constantly overriding the cloud backup to do the local backup and therefore it never seems to get anywhere with the cloud backup (it's been at 1.8 TB deficit for months now).  The flip side is that because the cloud backup is at this 1.8 TB deficit, I can't disable the local backup entirely (to let the cloud backup hopefully complete over time) since it's really our only fail-safe.

What I've been thinking about is trying to separate the local external drive backup from the cloud backup and hopefully then they can both operate at the same time and that way we'll continue to be protected locally while the cloud backup can also continually work until it eventually catches up.  CrashPlan can't do this though as I can't run two instances of the program on the server, so I need something else I can use for backing up data to the local external drive while I tell CrashPlan to just focus exclusively on the cloud backup - any suggestions/thoughts?  I don't believe WinServer 2012 R2 Essentials has the Win8/8.1/10 File History feature on it so I can't use that - but if there is some built-in Windows backup mechanism for WinServer 2012 R2 Essentials that might work best that would be great.  Otherwise I guess I'll have to find some 3rd party tool.

I know I'm not supposed to ask about software comparisons on here, but this question is really more to see if the above scenarios makes sense and whether there is a built-in WinServer 2012 R2 Essentials mechanism to backup up data on a constant basis to a local external drive (sort of like how File History works).  Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: 2012R2 Essentials should include Windows Server Backup.

Comment: I haven't used Windows Server Backup in a while though, and my recollection of it is that it will do things like bare metal backup but wasn't the best tool to use for file version history backups (and recovery of different files, or different versions of a file, etc.) - has that changed in WinServer 2012 R2 Essentials?  Thanks.